# Edit People template on results.aspx

Tags: search-results, people-search

How can I customize, or at least identify, which is the template used in the results.aspx page? 
On peopleresults.aspx, which is the page shown when selecting tab "People", the template is item_person.html, but this doesn't seem to be the case for People results under tab "Everything".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the person group item on the results.aspx (Everything) tab, that uses the compact person item I believe. You can create new templates rather than change the out of the box templates. Here is the process: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed Item_Person_CompactHorizontal.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about display templates:

/_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/search/item_person.js <- renders result panel
/_catalogs/masterpage/display%20templates/search/item_person_hoverpanel.js <- renders hover panel